# Node.js mongoose has no method 'save'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, this is the error:

```
/dev/sth-srv/app/services/notify.js:23

Notify.save(function() {
 TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
  if (!(this instanceof model))
     return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
  Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
} has no method 'save'
```

this is model (date is stringified because I wanted to be sure that I'm not doing anything wrong in here):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var notifySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    to : String,
    type : String,
    date : String,
    what : String,
    who : String,
    status : String
});
mongoose.model('Notify', notifySchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Notify', notifySchema);
```

this is object that reaches save method

```
{ 
type: 'vote',
date: 'Sat Feb 21 2015 11:33:58 GMT+0100 (CET)',
what: 'asdgf12',
who: 'demouser',
status: 1,
to: 'demouser' 
}
```

this is call for save:

```
var notify = new Notify(notifyBody);
Notify.save(function() {
    /.../
});
```

What makes me unable to figure it out is that it is working in many situations for other models but not this particular one.

Last important info:
This save func is not called directly from routing but from another file with module.exports. (Model is required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call save on the object created using the new keyword, instead of the model.

```
var notify = new Notify(notifyBody);

//save needs to be called on notify, not Notify
notify.save(function() {
    /.../
});
```